# Generic way to divide the process into sub processes

Tags: java

I am working on Spring based standalone application , Once xml message enter into system .We are doing some technical validations using java code using exceptions and regular expressions.Now i am trying to plugin one more feature ,based on some flag in the database we need few more validations on incoming xml message, but all existing clients dont require. I know there is a concept fork/join in java 7.But i am limited upto java 1.6. So how can i implement similar feature using java 1.6.

Below is the approach .

main class -handler thread--> calls action class --->every action class extends abstract action class-->performs technical validations using xml file.

```
public class AbstractAction {

public abstract void  processMsg(String msg);


}


public Class GenericAction extends AbstractAction {


public void processMsg(String str){


// existing code already doing validations

//now i have to check flag in table ,whether that client requires new validations,these validations are in xml file in the form of spring beans.

//Java code read that bean validate using some helper classes.There is no third party code here,Here i want to put some new code.So i have to break down existing into 

//some small piceses




}


}
```

Regards,

chaitu hara

Comment: [Message Queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) might be appropriate (either via a library/subsystem or simple queue wrapper) to consider. Of course you'll need to program how "based on some flag" should work ..

Comment: Is this really a Fork/Join question? Sounds like you just need to check the client and the message and then optionally do more work on the message.

Comment: similar concept i have to implement probably